# Using Interfaces on Pascal Script

Tags: delphi, pascalscript

I´m trying to use interfaces on REM Objects Pascal Script and having some dificulties.

My app has a variable of type TXMLDocument and I´m exposing it to my scripts. Although I can compile my test scripts, the problem is to make them run properly.

```
LogInfo(XMLDoc.XML.Text);
```

works OK when I run my scripts, but

```
procedure OnMapEvent(var Value:Variant); //LINE1
var
  lNode: IXMLNode;
begin
  lNode := XMLDoc.DocumentElement; (AV occurs HERE)
  LogInfo('lNode.NodeName: ' + lNode.GetNodeName);
end;
```

does not work fine, ie, trying to access any Interface reference is problematic. DocumentElement should result an IXMLNode, but I get an AV (Exception: Access violation at address 0040820C in module 'Flow.exe'. Read of address 00000000) and basically nothing else works.

Does Pascal Script support correctly Interface objects or Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It seems it is a bug, as stated by RemObjects support [link](http://connect.remobjects.com/discussion/3639/importing-interfaces#latest). Unfortunatelly they won´t fix it too soon as the product seems deprecated.